# Updating Nested Objects in Vue using VeeValidate Form issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I am using Vee-Validate with VueQuery in order to create a Form

VueQuery is used to fetch intial form data
Vee-Validate is used to handle the Form values and Validations

I am facing problem when i try to update the form values and track the changes.

Whenever i send the data flat as formValues.authData as intial-values, i can track the changes and get them reflected. whenever i pass the formValues on it's own. the values inside these nested objects can't be changed or tracked. i am thinking about problem in the reactivity of the nested objects as they can't be tracked

In this example i will use 4 Components

1. GeneralSettings Component (Parent Component that contains the Form)
2. AdminInfo Component (Component that contains values related to admin)
3. BasicInfo Component (Component that contains values related to companies)
4. ZamTextFieldForm Component. (Custom Input Component)

**GeneralSettings.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="companyIsLoading || authIsLoading">Loading please wait...</div>
  <div v-else>
    <Form v-slot="{ values }" :initial-values="formValues">
      <div>
        <admin-info />
        <pre>{{ values }}</pre>
      </div>
      <q-separator class="q-mt-md" />
      <div v-if="companyIsLoading">Loading...</div>
      <div v-else>
        <basic-info />
      </div>
      <q-separator class="q-mt-md" />
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import useCompanyDetailsQuery from "src/composables/useCompanyDetailsQuery";
import useAuthInfoQuery from "src/composables/useAuthInfoQuery";
import AdminInfo from "./AdminInfo.vue";
import BasicInfo from "./BasicInfo.vue";
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
import { Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import auth from "src/store/auth";
import { useForm } from "vee-validate";

const {
  data: companyData,
  isLoading: companyIsLoading,
  error: companyError,
} = useCompanyDetailsQuery();

const {
  data: authData,
  isLoading: authIsLoading,
  error: authError,
} = useAuthInfoQuery();

const formValues = ref({
  authData,
  companyData,
});
</script>
```

**AdminInfo.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="ContainerHeading q-pa-sm">
    {{ "Admin Info" }}
  </div>

  <div class="shadow-2 q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-md row q-pa-sm">
      <ZamFormField name="authData.name" label="Name" class="input-field" />
      <ZamFormField name="authData.email" label="Email" class="input-field" />
      <ZamFormField
        name="authData.phoneNumber"
        label="Phone Number"
        class="input-field"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import ZamFormField from "components/ZamFormField.vue";
</script>

<style>
.input-field {
  width: 33%;
}
</style>
```

**BasicInfo.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="ContainerHeading q-pa-sm">
    {{ "Company Info" }}
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-2 q-pa-md">
    <section class="q-gutter-md row q-pa-sm">
      <ZamFormField
        name="companyData.company.basicInfo.name"
        label="Company Name"
        class="input-field"
      />

      <ZamFormField
        name="companyData.company.basicInfo.url"
        label="url"
        class="input-field"
      />

      <ZamFormField
        name="companyData.company.basicInfo.contactPhone"
        label="Phone Number"
        class="input-field"
      />
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ZamFormField from "components/ZamFormField.vue";
export default {
  name: "BasicInfo",
  components: {
    ZamFormField,
  },
  props: {
    basicInfo: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      info: this.basicInfo,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    basicInfo: function (value) {
      this.info = value;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.input-field {
  width: 33%;
}
</style>
```

**ZamFormField.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { toRef } from "vue";
import { useField } from "vee-validate";

const props = defineProps({
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "text",
  },
  value: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  successMessage: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  placeholder: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
});
const name = toRef(props, "name");
const {
  value: inputValue,
  errorMessage,
  handleChange,
  meta,
} = useField(name, undefined, {
  initialValue: props.value,
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <label :for="name">{{ label }}</label>
    <input
      :name="name"
      :id="name"
      :type="type"
      :value="inputValue"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      @input="handleChange"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are expecting vee-validate to update the `formValues` prop which isn't a correct assumption, since:

- It is not two-way binding like with `v-model`
- vee-validate does not emit changes from the form component.

You should instead use `useForm` since you want access to your form values and remove the `Form` component. I see it is already imported for some reason.

```js
const { values, resetForm } = useForm();


// Wait for the data to load, or you can use `until` from `@vueuse/core` with the mounted lifecycle hook.
watch([authIsLoading, companyIsLoading], ([auth, company]) => {
  if (auth || company) {
    return;
  }

  // sets initial and current values.
  resetForm({ values: { ...authData.value, ...companyData.value } });
});
```